# Exporting SQL data to Excel without losing the 0 in the phone number

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, format, phone-number

I currently have a simple database which stores a customers basic table. However when ever I try to export my sql query to Excel the phone number field always appears without a 0.

My SQL query results:

```
ID | Name |Address |DOB         | Gender |Phone_Number   |
---------------------------------------------------------
01 | Max  |Abc Road| 2000-12-19 | Male   |07777 893 8902 |
02 | Sam  |TBH Road| null       | Male   |077778938902   |
03 | Doe  |Dr  Road| 1999-11-13 | Male   |077778 938902  |
```

What I get in Excel:

```
ID | Name |Address |DOB         | Gender |Phone_Number   |
---------------------------------------------------------
01 | Max  |Abc Road| 2000-12-19 | Male   |07777 893 8902 |
02 | Sam  |TBH Road|            | Male   |77778938902    |
03 | Doe  |Dr  Road| 1999-11-13 | Male   |077778 938902  |
```

However what I want to get this without having to format the cells in excel:

```
    ID | Name |Address |DOB         | Gender |Phone_Number   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    01 | Max  |Abc Road| 2000-12-19 | Male   |07777 893 8902 |
    02 | Sam  |TBH Road|            | Male   |077778938902   |
    03 | Doe  |Dr  Road| 1999-11-13 | Male   |077778 938902  |
```

My SQL query at the moment is as following:

```
SELECT 
ID,
isnull(Gender,'') Gender,
isnull(Name,'') Name,
isnull(Address,'') Address,
isnull(DOB,'') DOB,
isnull(Gender,'') Gender,
isnull(Phone_Numer,'') Phone_Number
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting a single quote ( ' ) as first character when you write that to Excel. Should format the cell to text.

Comment: Be careful with this solution tho, the single quote will not be displayed, however the value of the cell will still contain it. Paste values to a different column should solve that, if need be.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an apostrophe, to tell excel to treat it as text...

```
    SELECT 
    ID,
    isnull(Gender,'') Gender,
    isnull(Name,'') Name,
    isnull(Address,'') Address,
    isnull(DOB,'') DOB,
    isnull(Gender,'') Gender,
    '''' + isnull(Phone_Numer,'') Phone_Number
    FROM CUSTOMER;
```